# Iteration of ST_GeneratePoints results in identical points

Tags: postgis

I am relatively new to doing this type of operation from SQL so perhaps I have made an poor assumption.  The code below results in the exact same points being generated n times.  I am trying to repeat the creation of random points n times.  For the sake of this test the number of points is set to 10 but will vary by sample.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION repeating_random_tree_generator(n INTEGER)
    RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
    --clean up
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS random_trees;

    --new table
    CREATE TABLE random_trees (
        run_number int,
        tree bigint
    );
    --ADD POINT GEOMETRY UTM 11 N
    PERFORM AddGeometryColumn ('public','random_trees','geom',26911,'POINT',2);
    FOR i in 1..n LOOP
        --create 10 random points in box
        CREATE TABLE temp_random_trees as (
        SELECT (row_number() over ()) as 
            tree,
            geom 
         from 
            (SELECT 
                (ST_Dump
                    (ST_GeneratePoints(
                        ST_GeomFromText('Polygon ((553690 5435710, 553690 5435700, 553700 5435700, 553700 5435710, 553690 5435710))',26911)
                        , 10)
                    )
                ).geom) r
        );
        --add to random tree table
        INSERT INTO random_trees (
            SELECT 1,tree,geom from temp_random_trees
        );
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_random_trees;

    END LOOP;
RETURN;
END;$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is likely looking at `now` to seed the random number generator with the current time... unfortunately, this time is set for the entire transaction.

If you call `ST_GeneratePoints` twice, it will create different results.

```sql
select st_asText(ST_GeneratePoints(ST_GeomFromText('Polygon ((1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 1 2, 1 1))'),1));
                   st_astext
-----------------------------------------------
 MULTIPOINT(1.75170140690329 1.88128299813837)
(1 row)


select st_asText(ST_GeneratePoints(ST_GeomFromText('Polygon ((1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 1 2, 1 1))'),1));
                   st_astext
-----------------------------------------------
 MULTIPOINT(1.75200659199805 1.86532181768242)
(1 row)
```

If you wrap two call within a transaction, they will both return the same result.

```sql
BEGIN;
    select st_asText(ST_GeneratePoints(ST_GeomFromText('Polygon ((1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 1 2, 1 1))'),1));
    select st_asText(ST_GeneratePoints(ST_GeomFromText('Polygon ((1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 1 2, 1 1))'),1));
END;

st_astext
-----------------------------------------------
 MULTIPOINT(1.75859859004486 1.51432844019898)
(1 row)

                   st_astext
-----------------------------------------------
 MULTIPOINT(1.75859859004486 1.51432844019898)
(1 row)
```

Your function being a transaction, each call returns the same result.

To workaround this limitation, you could modify your function to insert 1 set of results, and call several times this function.

You can also change the function to generate n * 10 random points, and to later assign a "run id" for each group of 10.

At last, let's note that in PostGIS 3, the function `ST_GeneratePoints` will accept a `seed` argument, allowing you to use `clock_timestamp()` instead of `now()` (the former being the true time, not the transaction time)

Comment: Perfect -  I understand that.  Thank you for taking the time to answer.